# Why I can't use javascript any hosting (Except PC)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://community.wikidot.com/local--files/howto:sortable-tables-js/sorttable.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  th, td {
    padding: 3px !important;
  }
  table.sortable thead {
      background-color:#eee;
      color:#666666;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: default;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="sortable">
<thead>
<tr>
<td><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Salary</strong></td>
<td><strong>Extension</strong></td>
<td><strong>Start Date</strong></td>
<td><strong>Start Date(American)</strong></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Bloggs, Fred</td>
<td>$12000.00</td>
<td>1353</td>
<td>18/08/2003</td>
<td>08/18/2003</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Shakespeare, Hamnet</td>
<td>$9000</td>
<td>9005</td>
<td>01/01/2002</td>
<td>01/01/2002</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mbogo, Arnold</td>
<td>$32010.12</td>
<td>2755</td>
<td>09/08/1998</td>
<td>08/09/1998</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Fitz, Marvin</td>
<td>$3300</td>
<td>5554</td>
<td>22/05/1995</td>
<td>05/22/1995</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Turvey, Kevin</td>
<td>$191200.00</td>
<td>2342</td>
<td>02/05/1979</td>
<td>05/02/1979</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Shakespeare, Bill</td>
<td>$122000.00</td>
<td>3211</td>
<td>12/11/1961</td>
<td>11/12/1961</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
<td>$369510</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I works fine on PC by sorting the table, But when I upload this HTML file to my host, the sort table doesn't work. Could the host be disabling Javascript for me?

I using GoogleDrive to host. I have tried Dropbox, but it doesn't work either.

Example table: https://2cdf7d8230e2b51a89d897a354b906bcb02dfca8.googledrive.com/host/0B_WPAWweGO9mfnpGM1FNR0pLZ1VEQlJHQzNJMGRrd3hwaW9WTjg0aE91MG1uZkhCQzJWRzQ/heroes-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome reports:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://2cdf7d8230e2b51a89d897a354b906bcb02dfca8.googledrive.com/host/0B_WP…pGM1FNR0pLZ1VEQlJHQzNJMGRrd3hwaW9WTjg0aE91MG1uZkhCQzJWRzQ/heroes-data.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://community.wikidot.com/local--files/howto:sortable-tables-js/sorttable.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

In summary: `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Your Google Drive website is running under HTTPS, but the requested javascript is being linked via HTTP. You need to match protocols, otherwise the browser will get suspicious and block the linked script.

I'm going to assume Google Drive files have to be served via HTTPS, so you can't change that. But what you can change is the protocol of the linked script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//community.wikidot.com/local--files/howto:sortable-tables-js/sorttable.js"></script>
```

I removed `http:` from the src URL so that it is 'protocol-less' and will adapt to whatever the current document is served within, in this case HTTPS. Now it should match and load correctly. You're also lucky that the site serving the file is able to serve over HTTPS (they have an SSL certificate).

Answer (score 1):

You should see this error in your browser console:

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://2cdf7d8230e2b51a89d897a354b906bcb02dfca8.googledrive.com/host/0B_WP…pGM1FNR0pLZ1VEQlJHQzNJMGRrd3hwaW9WTjg0aE91MG1uZkhCQzJWRzQ/heroes-data.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://community.wikidot.com/local--files/howto:sortable-tables-js/sorttable.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

That means that the js library you use is called with http, while the html page is served with https. 
You just have to change the library url scheme like that: https://community.wdfiles.com/local--files/howto%3Asortable-tables-js/sorttable.js

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//community.wikidot.com/local--files/howto:sortable-tables-js/sorttable.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  th, td {
    padding: 3px !important;
  }
  table.sortable thead {
      background-color:#eee;
      color:#666666;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: default;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="sortable">
<thead>
<tr>
<td><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Salary</strong></td>
<td><strong>Extension</strong></td>
<td><strong>Start Date</strong></td>
<td><strong>Start Date(American)</strong></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Bloggs, Fred</td>
<td>$12000.00</td>
<td>1353</td>
<td>18/08/2003</td>
<td>08/18/2003</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Shakespeare, Hamnet</td>
<td>$9000</td>
<td>9005</td>
<td>01/01/2002</td>
<td>01/01/2002</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mbogo, Arnold</td>
<td>$32010.12</td>
<td>2755</td>
<td>09/08/1998</td>
<td>08/09/1998</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Fitz, Marvin</td>
<td>$3300</td>
<td>5554</td>
<td>22/05/1995</td>
<td>05/22/1995</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Turvey, Kevin</td>
<td>$191200.00</td>
<td>2342</td>
<td>02/05/1979</td>
<td>05/02/1979</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Shakespeare, Bill</td>
<td>$122000.00</td>
<td>3211</td>
<td>12/11/1961</td>
<td>11/12/1961</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
<td>$369510</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```